# How to view the output of pipelinedRdd in apyori?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to do an apriori algorithm on a set of transactions. Following is the code:

```
apr_tem=DescriptionGrp.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], [x[1]]).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y))
transactions_mba=apr_tem.map(lambda x: (x[1]))
association_rules_mba=apriori(transactions_mba,min_support=0.5,min_confidence=0.7,min_lift=1.2,min_length=2)
association_rules_mba = list(association_rules_mba)#error here
```

I am using python 2.7 with apyori and jupyter notebooks. However I am getting an error in the last line of the code.

`TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PipelinedRDD is not an iterable object. However it can be converted into a list using .collect()

So the piece of code should be:

```
association_rules_mba=apriori(transactions_mba.collect(),min_support=0.5,min_confidence=0.7,min_lift=1.2,min_length=2)
```

The real problem however was the support was too high and the apriori didn't return any results (association rules)

So the support was reduced to '0.002' and the issue is corrected

```
association_rules_mba=apriori(transactions_mba,min_support=0.002,min_confidence=0.7,min_lift=1.2,min_length=2)
```